# Running glassfish from Intellij Idea 13: 'java' not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish

My local glassfish installation works perfectly when I run it manually. However when I try to run glassfish from my Intellij Idea 13 IDE I get this error:

```
D:\Project\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat start-domain domain1
[2014-08-07 05:02:51,719] Artifact My_Project:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I can't seem to find out what is going wrong. The java command works if I try it out in cmd. In the project settings it points to the correct java installation. I get this error regardless if I check or uncheck the 'Use alternative JRE' option for the glassfish application server.

Answer (score 6):

Update the file

> C:\glassfish\config\asenv.bat

setting path like below, setting your JDK path

> set AS_JAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25