# InteliJ Java is not recegonized

Tags: java

I reinstalled windows and I have a problem with the InteliJ.

When I run some Spring project on Glass Fish I'm getting:

```
'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
 operable program or batch file.
```

I'm getting info when run `java -version` and `javac -versio`n in cmd.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion from this Stack Overflow question: [Running glassfish from Intellij Idea 13: 'java' not recognized as an internal or external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25186115/running-glassfish-from-intellij-idea-13-java-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or/27170879)

Comment: I don't use InteliJ but this sounds like you need to configure your per-project run-time environment (JRE), https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-change-java-version

Or, possibly ensure that your JAVA_HOME is set.

Comment: What does `where java` output in cmd?